# post_url causing build failure with github

Tags: github, jekyll

I am trying to link to another post in my blog. The markdown for both the blog resides in the same folder under _posts. However, when I try to use post_url I always get a build failure with github.

This is how i am declaring it in my markdown.

```
[Part2 - Details about PyVM and the execution of VM]({% post_url 2016-01-06-PyVyM-Part2 %})
```

I am adding the code for the post_url in the PyVym-Introduction file.

My .config.yml looks like this.

```
# Build settings
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true
permalink: pretty
highlighter: pygments
```

[image]

If I remove the post_url code then there are no build failures. Can someone point me to the mistake here ?

[edited]: github failure email has no error message. It just says build failed.. Exact message below..
"""
The page build failed with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-build-failures.
"""

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the error message that you get when the build fails?

Comment: does `{% post_url 2016-01-06-PyVyM-Part2 %}` by itself generate a url?

Comment: That's what I thought it does. All examples say that this should generate a URL. Am guessing it should generate a url (whether valid or not). However it causes a build failure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using another repository named "pretty" with a gh-pages branch?

Github warns of duplicating these URL's [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#troubleshooting)

> If you are having issues with your Jekyll Pages, make sure you are not using categories that are named the same as another project, as this could cause path conflicts. For example: if you have a blog post named 'resume' in your User Page repository and a project named 'resume' with a gh-pages branch, they will conflict with each other.

Comment: Nopes.. I just have the master branch since this is a repo for user pages. Not even a project page.